Debugging error with React Native Tools VSCode
I'm experiencing an error while using the React Native Tools extension in Visual Studio Code. Here are the details:
Environment:

Operating System: macOS Monterey M1 Pro
React Native Version: 0.74
Node.js Version: v22.2.0
Project Template: TypeScript template

Error Description:
Whenever I try to debug my React Native project, I encounter the following error:
Launching the application
An error occurred while launching the application. Cannot find module '/Users/is789/Desktop/NextCall/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/config/findXcodeProject'
Require stack:
/Users/is789/.vscode/extensions/msjsdiag.vscode-react-native-1.13.0/dist/rn-extension.js
/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/loader.js
/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/bootstrap-amd.js
/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/bootstrap-fork.js (error code
303)
Steps to Reproduce:

Open my React Native project in VSCode.
Click on the debug icon in the sidebar.
Select "Debug iOS Hermes".
The error occurs after starting building the project.

What I've Tried:

Reinstalled the React Native Tools extension.
Cleared VSCode cache and settings.
Deleted node_modules and ran npm install.
Verified the React Native CLI is installed and working.
Restarted my computer.

Important to mention:

The project works fine when running from the terminal using react-native run-ios.
I have tried creating a new React Native project and the issue persists.
I can debug my project using Chrome DevTools by going to chrome://inspect/#devices and adding a new port. This method works without any issues.
It seems like the module @react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/config/findXcodeProject cannot be found, even though it should be part of the standard React Native setup.
Error:


Hi, here is a similar ticket.Please check it to see if it can help.
